# How to define new variable as float?

Tags: python

I'm trying to make the following function output the correct answer, but the 'rightSide' variable is being made as an integer, and doesn't have any decimals.

```
def G(mass1, mass2, radius, force):
    rightSide=(mass1*mass2)/(radius**2) #I want this to be a float
    print rightSide
    if rightSide==0:
        print("The operation resulted in a zero, error!")
    else:
        answer=force/rightSide
        print(str(answer)+" is the gravitation constant (G)!")
```

I just want all the variables to be floats, but the problem starts with 'rightSide'.

I tried the following with no success:

```
float(rightSide)=(mass1*mass2)/(radius**2)
  --
rightSide=(float(mass1)*float(mass2))/(float(radius)**2)
```

Any tips? Thanks!

Nevermind, I just re-ran the second code that I hand typed in the question and it worked -_-

Comment: `rightSide=(float(mass1)*float(mass2))/(float(radius)**2)` - if that didn't work, you have problems even earlier than this. That one should have worked.

Comment: Well that's just great, I ran the exact code I put on this question and it worked... Thanks for making me try it again :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
def G(mass1, mass2, radius, force):
    rightSide = (float(mass1)*mass2) / (radius**2) #I want this to be a float
    print rightSide
    if rightSide==0:
        print("The operation resulted in a zero, error!")
    else:
        answer=force/rightSide
        print(str(answer)+" is the gravitation constant (G)!")
```

Answer (score 4):

In general

```
x = float(2)
```

Or

```
y = 10
x = float(y)
```

In your case,

```
rightSide=float((mass1*mass2)/(radius**2))
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to make one of the inputs a floating point value. Try changing `2` to `2.0`. E.g.:

```
>>> x=10
>>> x**2
100
>>> x**2.0
100.0
```

Note that in Python 3 [division automatically returns a floating point](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0238/), and the new `//` operator explicitly does integer division.